# I want to retrieve only id number in one table but not in another table

Tags: sql

Below is table 1

```
select  
    nContractPk 
from 
    CustomerPayment 
where 
    nContractPk in (select id            
                    from Contract 
                    where id in (SELECT nContractPk
                                 FROM CustomerPayment
                                 GROUP BY nContractPk
                                 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN bPaid <> 1 THEN 1 END) = 0 
                                    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN bPaid = 1 THEN 1 END) > 1) 
                                    AND nStatus = 10)
```

This is the second table:

```
select  
    nContractPk 
from
    EmployeePayment  
where 
    nContractPk in (select id    
                    from Contract 
                    where id in (SELECT nContractPk
                                 FROM EmployeePayment
                                 GROUP BY nContractPk
                                 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN bPaid <> 1 THEN 1 END) = 0 
                                    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN bPaid = 1 THEN 1 END) > 1) 
                                    AND nStatus = 10)
```

I want to retrieve only id exits in customerpayment but not in employeepayment

Please help with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try LEFT join between the two tables and filter out null from the other as below:

```
SELECT c.nContractPk
FROM CustomerPayment c LEFT JOIN EmployeePayment e
ON c.nContractPk = e.nContractPk
WHERE e.nContractPk IS NULL
```